# Cannot load mod_wsgi into server:

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf

I want to install mod_wsgi-4.4.11 so that I can use Django and apache for local web development but I am unsuccessful. These are the steps/commands that I have taken in my attempts to install mod_wsgi-4.4.11. I am using the Apple system python version. I downloaded mod_wsgi-4.4.11 according to the quick instructions from code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide. The steps/commands that used were as follows:

1) Downloaded mod_wsgi as a zip, cd to the folder 2)./configure 3) make 4) sudo make install 4) added the line LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so to the http.conf file, stopped and started apache server 5) httpd -t.

I receive the following error.

Syntax error on line 172 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so, 10): Symbol not found: _PyBool_Type\n  Referenced from: /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so\n  Expected in: flat namespace\n in /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so

I cd to /usr/libexec/apache2 and I run otool -L mod_wsgi.so and the output is:

mod_wsgi.so:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1153.18.0)
Daniels-MacBook-Pro:apache2 Daniel$

Makefile when configure was run:

LDFLAGS = LDFLAGS =  -L/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib -L/Library/Frameworks/

LDLIBS =  -lpython2.7 -ldl  -framework CoreFoundation

It was suggested that I use pip to install mod_wsgi. I followed the instructions from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi/4.4.11. The commands/actions I took were as follows:
1) Upgraded pip to 6.1.1
2) pip install mod_wsgi (installed successfully)
3) ran mod_wsgi-express start-server
4) Received error: ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8

When I run the locale command the LANG variable is assigned to nothing it looks like this:
LANG =

Comment: Are you using Apple system Python version or a version from brew or some other package system? What version of mod_wsgi are you using? Did you start with fresh mod_wsgi source code which had never been compiled in before? What actual commands did you use to compile/install mod_wsgi?

Comment: I am using the Apple system python version. I downloaded and attempted to install mod_wsgi-4.4.11 according to the quick instructions from https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide. The steps/commands that used were as follows: Downloaded mod_wsgi as a zip, cd to the folder, ran ./configure, make, sudo make install, added the line  LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so to the http.conf file, stopped and restarted apache server, ran httpd -t....Thanks for any help that you may be able to provide.

Comment: Amend your question and add the output of running ``otool -L /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so``.

Comment: To separately verify whether it should work, you can also try the 'pip' installable version of mod_wsgi. This will not touch your system Apache. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Comment: Thanks, I ammended the question. I will try with pip as you suggest.

Comment: Add to your question what the ``LDFLAGS`` and ``LDLIBS`` are set to in the Makefile that was generated when you ran ``configure``. The output of ``otool -L`` shows that the Python framework library isn't even being linked into mod_wsgi properly.

Comment: For the locale issue with mod_wsgi-express, what is ``LANG`` environment variable set to in your user environment?  Are you sure you do not have some other Python version installed on your system, or have you ever tried to install one yourself.

Comment: I added your suggestions to the question. I installed IDLE a while ago, but I thought that I also uninstalled it completely. I have a suspicion now that, this is not the case. I will check this, and finish the job if need be.

Comment: Yep. You have a non Apple Python installation under '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework' which seems to be breaking things. Usually this shouldn't be a problem so long as the 'python' found in the PATH when configure is run is still '/usr/bin/python' and that refers to the normal Apple Python installation. You could try using ``--with-python /usr/bin/python`` option to 'configure' if the other installation is appearing in PATH first. If /usr/bin/python has been overridden to refer to the alternate installation, that is bad.

Comment: I ran ./configure --with-python /usr/bin/python. The program ran outputting configure: WARNING: invalid host type: /usr/bin/python amongst other things. When the program got to checking Apache version... 2.4.10. Terminal began acting weird and my MBP started making a loud humming noise. I had to restart the computer to make it stop. My conclusion is. It's bad. Thanks anyway for the help. I am still open to further suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like your whole system is screwed up in some way. That configure script in itself shouldn't be able to break things that bad.

Answer (score 0):

I restored the state of my system to a point before I installed IDLE, followed the installation instructions listed above and successfully installed and loaded the module. I then followed the instructions to configure the application (https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide) and successfully printed out hello world. Since the configuration guide was a bit confusing I used the google group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/modwsgi) which helped to answer my questions during this process. In case anyone has a similar problem.